# Can I execute an SQL Server DTS package from a Python script?

Tags: python, sql-server

I currently have a number of Python scripts that help prep a staging area for testing. One thing that the scripts do not handle is executing DTS packages on MS SQL Server. Is there a way to execute these packages using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. As mentioned by lansinwd, you'd want to use the command line tool [DTSRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224467%28SQL.80%29.aspx). SQL Server tools will need to be installed on the machine executing the Python script. I'm not sure what percentage or which packages would be needed but the [MSDN page on DTSRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224467%28SQL.80%29.aspx) should help answer that, if needed.

A basic command line example is this:

```
DTSRun /S "Server[\Instance]" /N "DTS_Package_Name" /E
```

To [run this from Python](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#process-management) check out: http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#process-management

From the web page:

> These functions may be used to create
>   and manage processes.
>
> The various exec*() functions take a
>   list of arguments for the new program
>   loaded into the process

Answer (score 1):

Is calling the DTS run from the command line an option.  If so here is an example for that.

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1007